# Issue with downcasting Picture

Tags: java, bufferedimage, downcast

I am stuck with a downcasting issue with java.

Here is the plot:
The class `MyPicture` extends the abstract class `BufferedImage`. The point is to add a few methods to `BufferedImage`. Then, I have the class `MyWindow` which sets a user-friendly window. In this class, I want to load a picture in `MyPic`, copy it in `MyPic_filtered`, use a method used in `MyPicture` on `MyPic_filtered` and finally show `MyPic` and `MyPic_filtered` in separated windows (but this last part is OK ^^).
I don't know which types I should use for `MyPic` and `MyPic_filtered`. I tried the cast them in the right type, it builds but doesn't run.

Here is the code:

```
//Loading the picture
BufferedImage MyPic = ImageIO.read(new File(URL)); //URL is a string
//Copy the picture 
MyPicture myPic_filtered = myPic;               
//Use the method from MyPicture
myPic_filtered.method_from_MyPicture();`
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: `ImageIO.read()` doesn't return a `MyPicture`.  You cannot magically turn an object into a type that it isn't.

Comment: Also Java is case-sensitive, so `MyPic != myPic`

Comment: *The class `MyPicture` extends the abstract class `BufferedImage`*... This statement is incorrect. `BufferedImage` isn't abstract. There's generally no need to extend it, and I would advice against it. Use delegation instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a caster when you are trying to pass a base class instance to extended one, like:

```
MyPicture myPic_filtered = (MyPicture)myPic;
```

Then you can access "myPic" by using **this** keyword.

---

Or maybe you do not need to extend the BufferedImage. Just treat bufferedImage as an instance variable, like:

```
class MyPicture { 
    BufferedImage bi;
    //other variables
    ......;

    public MyPicture(BufferedImage input) {
          this.bi = input;
    }

    public BufferedImage method_from_MyPicture() {
         //Do something with bi and output
         ........
    }
}
```

Not sure which structure is better. But it solves the problem in either way.